# nunit and web.config appSettings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I am really new to testing, but I have an existing project that I want to test.
I have set up my test class like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class PiiikProviderTest
{
    public IList<GroupRequestModel> _groups;
    public IPiiikProvider _pickProvider;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var config = new PiiiCKConfig();
        var factory = new JsonFactory();
        var t = config.DocumentDbEnpointUrl;
        var settingProvider = new SettingProvider(config);

        _pickProvider = new PiiikProvider(settingProvider);
        _groups = factory.Groups();
    }

    [Test]
    public void ScoreShouldBe130()
    {

        // Assemble
        var products = new List<JObject>();
        var product = JObject.Parse("{'gtin': '8714574593609',    'model': 'EOS 6D',    'title': 'Canon EOS 6D Digital SLR Camera, HD 1080p, 20.2MP, GPS, 3\" LCD Screen, Body Only',    'shortTitle': 'Canon EOS 6D Black',    'image': 'http://piiick.blob.core.windows.net/images/Canon-EOS-6D-Black-8714574593609.png',    'weight': 'Heavy',    'size': 'Large',    'changableLens': 'Yes',    'action': 'No',    'sharing': 'Yes',    'mostlyManual': 'Yes',    'colour': 'Black',    'quality': 'Pro',    'type': 'DLSR',    'superzoom': 'No',    'video': 'HD',    'fastBurst': 'No',    'innovation': 'No',    'lowLight': 'Yes',    'brand': 'Canon',    'newestModels': 'No',    'focusTracking': 'No',    'wiFi': 'Yes',    'style': 'Traditional',    'categoryId': 1,    'id': '6cf8e9dd-4e7e-410e-b99e-c01005eb3f56'}");
        products.Add(product);

        // Act
        var response = _pickProvider.Score(_groups, products);
        var result = int.Parse(response[0].SelectToken("importance").ToString());

        // Asset
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(130));
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _groups = null;
        _pickProvider = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is, the `config.DocumentDbEnpointUrl` is always null.
I have tried many things, first I referenced the Api project that actually contains the **web.config** file.
That didn't work.

So I then added an existing item as a **link** to the test project and it still didn't work.

So then I created a new web.config file in the test project and copied the app settings across that that still did not work.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

Comment: copy the appSettings from the web.config into the app.config of the test project

Comment: That was it, can you post it as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to copy the `appSettings` from the *web.config* file into the *app.config* of the test project.

When running, the test project, it will get its configuration from its local configuration `{app name}.config`, which is what the app.config file will be transformed to when deployed/run

Comment: Adding following in the test method could also server the purpose, if not all the appsettings in web.config is required.

`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["settingsName"] = "settingsValue"; `